# Where must a PTR record point to in order to avoid being classified as a spammer?

Tags: dns, mx, spamming

We have a dedicated server for our website, and we also use it to send out bulk emails (ALWAYS by request, NEVER unsolicited or for spam). We are trying to set up a `PTR` record and there's one thing I simply can't understand:

If I send out email from *someone@example.com*, and example.com's `A` record is `x.x.x.x`, then in order for my IP not to be considered a spammer, the `PTR` record for `x.x.x.x` must point to:

1. example.com?
2. any of example.com's MX records?
3. the name of the domain as it appears in the SMTP banner you receive when connecting to example.com:25?
4. all/none/any of the above?

Answer (score 2):

A `PTR` record is used to map an IP address to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN). So basically the opposite of what an IP address does.

If you are worried about email spoofing, you may also want to set up an `SPF1` and `SPF2` record, which if set to a hard fail will also prevent spam being spoofed from your IP address/domain name.

However with regards to sending out bulk emails, from experience I would say don't. Firstly your IP address could easily be reported and blacklists which could interfere with your normally day-to-day emails being sent straight into the spam box.

You would be better off paying a little every month for an email manager which has already put all the effort in to getting their IP address white-listed. The last thing you want is to get your order received emails spammed as you have sent out a marketing campaign and a few too many people reporting it. My final point being that your ISP may also complain, as ours did, about the amount of emails sent out in such a short space of time - they also blocked our IP from sending emails temporarily.

So answering your question: A `PTR` record should resolve your IP to your FQDN. You can check your `PTR` record [here](http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/reverse_lookup.php) to verify it.

With regards to setting up `SPF` records, please see [here](http://www.openspf.org/) for more information. But if you want to use an `SPF` wizard to create the record for you, you can use one like [here](http://www.spfwizard.net).